# In Scala reflection, can one Universe have multiple Mirrors?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

In all subclasses of scala.reflection.api.Universe, I've never seen multiple implementations of Mirror. Does this means it is possible to merge Mirror with Universe. What is the design decision to separate Universe and Mirror?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a single *implementation* of Mirror for each Universe, but there can be many *instances*. Namely, in the runtime universe you have different mirrors for each `ClassLoader`.